# Is there a comprehensive list of searching algorithms for sorted (and possibly unsorted) arrays available anywhere?

Tags: algorithms, search-algorithms, search-problem, searching

Classic searching algorithms such as binary searching and dictionary searching search sorted arrays based on a given element and make estimations on their own. What I'm looking for is a list of more such algorithms to solve the generic problem- given a sorted array, find an element $x$ present in the array. I'd like to explore interesting methods to do it, but I'm not sure there's really another way besides binary/dictionary and linear searching. A list of algorithms would be appreciated!

Comment: What's wrong with the standard algorithms?  We discourage questions that ask for a big list of (something) with no criteria for choosing among them or evaluating answers.  If there is some specific requirement that the standard algorithms don't meet, then I suggest you revise your question to identify what are the specific criteria or requirements for an acceptable algorithm.

Comment: Please make it eye-catching whether you look for *finding a key in a "multiplicity" ordered by key*, [or something else](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_algorithm). What exactly makes an algorithm *interesting*? Note that looking up a word in a dictionary may include use of a *thumb index*, knowledge about the distribution of first/second characters, suprema at the top or bottom of pages, informed guessing about how far the place inspected may be from the word sought.

Comment: I doubt that there is anything called "dictionary searching" and in general a dictionary is not a sorted array. Searching a sorted array is done optimally by binary search for uniform distributions. For distribution biased toward the low values, linear and exponential searches can be used. For unsorted arrays, there is nothing better than linear search, possibly with "move-to-front" strategy.

Comment: "Searching a sorted array is done optimally by binary search for uniform distributions." This is true in the worst case, but not the average case. Interpolation search runs in $O(log(log(n))$ average time on a sorted array containing a uniform distribution. Variants that fall back to binary search "eventually" can retain the worst-case complexity of binary search while still attaining better average-case complexity.